# couldn't handle the bootstrap css

Tags: css, twig, bootstrap-4

I am new with bootstrap and I am using the default template,I have a form with labels and inputs what I have to do is puting all the labels on the **left**  then the inputs but I couldn’t put them in right format what I want is :

[image]

What I have is :
[image]

I couldnt figure how to handle col-sm-2 and col-sm-10" I have tired to devide 4columns then 8 columns but always messy (I have read  http://getbootstrap.com/css/ )

My code twig :

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr':{'class': 'form-horizontal'}}) }}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="namelabo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name Of laboratorie</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.namelabo, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="numberlabo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number laboratories</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.numberlabo, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="statuslabo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">The status of the laboratory</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.statuslabo, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="faxnumber" class="col-sm-2 control-label">fax number</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.faxnumber, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-mail</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With `col-sm-2` you take only 16,66% of width. Do you have try `col-sm-4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example, I want the same columns on every screen so I am using the classes `col-lg-x, col-md-x col-sm-x, col-xs-x`.

```css
.custom-locale-form {
  padding: 1.6rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container fluid custom-locale-form">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="language" class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 form-control-label">Label 1</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
        <input data-bind="value: language" type="text" class="form-control" id="language" placeholder="input1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="country" class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 form-control-label">Lablel 2</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
        <input data-bind="value: country" type="text" class="form-control" id="country" placeholder="input2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="variant" class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 form-control-label">Label 3 vary long</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
        <input data-bind="value: variant" type="text" class="form-control" id="variant" placeholder="input3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this tags after opening the form

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-6">

//your code 

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `col-sm-2` you take only 16,66% of width. Do you have try `col-sm-4`?

For Bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label ... class="col-sm-4 control-label">...</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
</div>
```

For Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label ... class="col-4 control-label">...</label>
    <div class="col-8">
</div>
```

I would advise you to use bootstrap 3, because 4 is still in the alpha.

Comment: how can the labels be aligned on the  left?